# Python Vigenère cipher not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, vigenere

I've created this code that uses the Vigenère cipher to encrypt a block of text, for some reason it's giving me this weird output

```
import string

original_word = raw_input("what text do you want to encrypt ?")
one_time_pad = raw_input("How do you want to encrypt ?")
word_array = list(original_word)
pad = list(one_time_pad)

i = 0
b = 0
for word in word_array:
    word_array[i]= chr(ord(word) + ord(pad[b]))
    print word_array
    i += 1
    if b == len(one_time_pad):
        b = 0
    else:
        b += 1

cipher_text = "".join(word_array)
print cipher_text
```

that only gives me this weird output

```
 ['\xc2', 'b', 'c']
  ['\xc2', '\xc4', 'c']
  ['\xc2', '\xc4', '\xc6']
  ???
```

Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: Please fix your indentation's code.

Comment: Also: `chr(ord('a') +ord('a'))` gives: '\xc2'. i think you may reconcider your algorithm. Or maybe can you explain how do your algorithm work ?

Comment: First thing ... `if b == len(one_time_pad)` should be checking for `len()-1` since `one_time_pad[len(one_time_pad)]` results in an `IndexError`.  Try using `b = (b + 1) % len(one_time_pad)` instead of the `if-else`.

Comment: Ok this is supposed to work by adding the values of the chars and outputing a new char in that place, I'm just confused about the output

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vigenere+python

Answer (score 0):

So the Vigenère cipher is defined on letters `[A-Z]`. You are using `ord()` to find the ASCII index of characters. However, [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) is defined over more than just the uppercase letters. For example:

```
>>> ord('m')
109
>>> ord('k')
107
>>> 216
```

The value of the 216th character is not defined in general ASCII, so Python when you use `chr()` to get the character, you will get `'\xd8'`, which is Python telling you that it is "just the `0xd8`th (is hex for 216)  character".

Instead you will want to remain in the range of uppercase letters. I would suggest to do the following:

```
ord1 = string.ascii_uppercase.index(word.upper())
ord2 = string.ascii_uppercase.index(pad[b].upper())
word_array[i] = string.ascii_uppercase[(ord1 + ord2) % 26]
```